# Restrict Solr results to category in SAP hybris

Tags: apache, solr, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

Hi am working on a project where the client wants to restrict the search result to relevant results. For example: if a user searches for 'mobile cases' then only mobile cases will show up, if searched for 'mobiles' only mobile phones will will come.I have categories for mobile phones and mobile cases though. But the implementing using out of the box feature is the challenge.

How to do it in SAP Hybris 6.7.0 ???

Comment: So what's the logic behind `mobiles` only matching `mobile phones` and not `mobile cases`? You're going to have to define this logic somewhere - for example by having a processed field that performs this mapping for you.

Comment: I was thinking maybe searching the category field, and limiting the matches to the names of items belonging to that category. Like searching with 'rubber mobile cases' , 'mobile cases' should match with the category field, and 'rubber', 'mobile' or 'cases' can match with any products  in that category. Currently, the result are a mess of mobiles, cases and rubbers!

Comment: But how would you determine that "mobile cases" is the relevant terms against category? What if you had "mobile rubber" as well, or "rubber mobiles"?

Comment: Yes, there maybe few discrepancies like you mentioned, and result may not be as relevant, but the database in our e-com site is limited and manageable for which I am optimizing the search, most of the main categories are distinguishable.

Comment: Checking www.amazon.com, they also hold true for this case. But searching with "samsung galaxy m30" gives Samsung Galaxy M30 phones and searching with "galaxy" gives galaxies from jewelry, phones, kids section, etc.

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying it's impossible, I'm saying you need a strategy to indicate what's important. Amazon has done that and has a lot of relevancy factors added into their search for specific queries. In your example you'd probably want to perform multiple searches and use what you find to refine the result before presenting it to the user; for example searching `rubber mobile cases` against a separate category core, then picking the two most popular (or single most popular) category to match against (then, you might want to use a different scoring to decide what the most popular is)

Comment: I have created a multi-valued category field, which has all the categories one item belongs to. Like a washing machine may belong to 'comfort' , 'household appliances' , 'washing machines' , etc. Similarly another item may belong to 'comfort' , 'household appliances' but not 'washing machines' . I want to have relevancy in my search result based on this field. Because I do not think querying multiple cores is possible in hybris.